# Does anyone have Oracle PL/SQL code to rename all synonyms to another schema?

Tags: linux, oracle, plsql

Oracle 11gR2
RHEL 6.4

---

Just exported a Oracle database user (schema) to another user using Data Pump.  But all the synonyms still point to old (original) user in the new schema.

Does anyone have some code (e.g. PL/SQL) that can be run to rename all the synonyms in the new schema so that they are owned (pointing to) new schema?

Comment: Private or public synonyms? If they're public and you recreate them, everyone will reference the new schema's objects, so you'd need to be sure that is what you want. Do you have a script that created the synonyms in the first place?

Comment: `CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM SCHEMA_A.MY_TABLE FOR SCHEMA_B.MY_TABLE;`  So the answer would be Private.

Answer (score 1):

The following will probably need some tweaking, but you can start with

```
DECLARE
  strSynonyms_owner       VARCHAR2(4000) := 'SOME_USER';
  strSynonyms_new_owner   VARCHAR2(4000) := 'NEW_USER';
  strCommand              VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  FOR aSynonym IN (SELECT *
                     FROM ALL_SYNONYMS
                     WHERE OWNER = strSynonyms_owner)
  LOOP
    strCommand := 'CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM ' ||
                  aSynonym.OWNER || '.' || aSynonym.SYNONYM_NAME ||
                  ' FOR ' || strSynonyms_new_owner || '.' ||
                  aSynonym.TABLE_NAME;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE strCommand;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

Not tested on animals - you'll be first!

Share and enjoy.

Comment: +1 for code AND not tested on animals. lol! Good luck to all.